# React: Sending props with redirect problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a sidebar, on which if you click on an element it will redirect you and also send props using react-router. The props are sent correctly and the right component is loaded when redirected. The component that is redirected to shows a table, which has pagination. So, if a change the pagination from 10 to 25 everything is okay, however, if I change the pagination from 25 back to 10 I get an error: *Cannot read property 'serial' of undefined*. I guess it is reloded, however, it doesn't get the props, since they are sent through redirect on click in sidebar. Does anyone know how I could solve this?

The componentDidUpdate in Table.js (the component which I am redirected to):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(this.props.location.state.serial != prevProps.location.state.serial){ //Here is where the error occurs - this.props.location.state.serial is undefined
```

The redirect in Sidebar.js:

```
<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/Table',
                state: {serial: this.state.serial}
                }}
/>
```

Also the componentDidUpdate works fine, if I click on another element on the sidebar.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

This is how I access the props in the componentDidMount and it works properly:

```
componentDidMount() {
        const database = db.ref().child("Devices/" + this.props.location.state.serial);
```

Comment: could you provide more code?

Comment: @ŁukaszKarczewski I added my componentDidMount(). Could you maybe specify which part of the code would be most useful to add? More from the componentDidUpdate?

Comment: Maybe the part where you pass props to the failing component

Comment: @ŁukaszKarczewski I pass the props in the redirect <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/Table',
                state: {serial: this.state.serial}
                }}
/>